# resized uiimagepickercontroller

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

How to get a resized uiimagepickercontroller, I mean non fullscreen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has to be full screen (that is, presented modally)… but you can add other views over the top by using `cameraOverlayView`. Combine that with scaling the camera feed's size with `cameraViewTransform`, and you can recreate bits of your UI inside the camera view itself.